# How to convert two rows into one column using pivot in sql

Tags: sql-server

I want  to convert two columns  into one row using **PIVOT FUNCTION** in `SQL` database.
But I'm facing problems. I can convert 1 column into 1 row but not 2 columns into 1 row.

Comment: We can't possibly answer your question based on this two sentence description.  Please include sample data which shows what you are trying to do here.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
Create Table Article (ArticleId Int, [Description] Varchar(10))
Insert Into Article Values (1, 'Test')

Create Table OrderForecast(ArticleId Int, [Week] Int, [Order] Int, Amount Int)
Insert Into OrderForecast Values (1, 51, 1, 0),(1, 52, 2, 150), (1, 1, 3, 0),(1, 2, 4, 200), (1, 3, 5,0)

Select ArticleId, [Description], Week51, Week52, Week1, Week2, Week3
from
(
  select ArticleId, [Description], Amount, [Week]
  from 
    (
    SELECT OrderForecast.ArticleId, 'Week' + Convert(Varchar(10), OrderForecast.[Week]) as [Week], [Order], Amount, 
        Article.[Description] as [Description] FROM OrderForecast
    Inner Join Article On OrderForecast.ArticleId = Article.ArticleId
    )a
) d
pivot
(
  max(Amount)
  for [Week] in (Week51, Week52, Week1, Week2, Week3)
) piv;
```

You can find the demo [**Here**](https://rextester.com/QTM43590)